# Converting factors to numeric in R

Tags: r

I have 100s of columns in my database as factors. They actually contains numbers, but R considers them as factors.  For my project requirement, I want to convert them to numeric.

I can do that in bulk using sapply / for loop. However i am not sure how to check that variable contains numbers? I cannot just check is.factor(var_name) as the data base also contains character variables which are considered as factors.

is there some other way to execute the below check:

```
if (is.numeric(var_name)) {
    convert the variable to numeric
}
```

I am looking for something similar to "stringasfactors= FALSE"
 which is used for retaining character variable  as a character variable instead of converting to factors.

Any help/pointer would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use `type.convert` after converting all the columns to `character`

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x)))
```

Now, the non-numeric character columns will be converted to `factor` class.  We can reconvert those columns back to `character`

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) if(is.factor(x)) as.character(x) else x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to retain the variables which is having the numbers as numeric instead of getting that converted to factors by R.

Comment: @Arun The code does that.  Here, I am assuming that you started with a dataset that have numeric values got converted to `factor` by some ways.  It shouldn't happen with the column contains only numeric values using `read.csv/read.table`.

Comment: thanks a lot akrun. I will try this and keep you posted

Comment: Just for info. I am not doing anything to convert the numeric variables to factors. As soon as i load the csv file in R, R by itself considering many variables to factors even though they have numbers. Is there any logic behind why R should do this?

Comment: they must have non-numeric values in them somewhere.

Comment: @Arun As BenBolker mentioned there must be non-numeric elements in that dataset which prevents the column from converting to `numeric`.  How big is the dataset? Also can you try `sum(grepl('^-*[0-9.]+$', yourdat$Col))==nrow(yourdat)` on that column which you suspect to be numeric.  Also check whether you have something like `#REF` in any of the cells?

Comment: @akrun thanks for the suggestion. I will check on this.

Comment: @BenBolker   - As you and akrun advised, the variables contains inherited commas. Hence the variable is being considered as a character(factor) variable by R.

Comment: @akrun - As advised by you Ben, the variables contain commas. Hence they were treated as non-numeric. Sorry i didnt noticed that. Also i am interested in knowing the sum(grepl) that you suggested. May i know the meaning of the same? When i tried, i got the following response > sum(grepl('^-*[0-9.]+$', train$Buy.Amount))==nrow(train$Buy.Amount)
===> logical(0)

Comment: @akrun - The code is converting the factor variable to a character. Is this what the code suppose to do. Sorry to ask this. But I am not able to figure it out the mistake that i am making.

Comment: @Arun  From your earlier comment, you have `,` inside the numbers.  If it is not decimal, I think the option would be to remove the `,` by `df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) as.numeric(gsub(',', '', x))`

Comment: @akrun - Thanks for the suggestions. I will check this.

Comment: @akrun - Thanks for the answer. It worked as always as any other answer from you :)

Comment: @Arun Thank you for the feedback.